# removeChild() working only for first child in list rendered with insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript

I have the following function for iterating through an array of activities and displaying them. The function also includes a trash-icon that is meant to clear away any specific item that is selected by clicking:

```
const renderList = (activities) => {
  const display = document.getElementById('task-list-display');
  activities.forEach((activity) => {
    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` 
    <li id="task-item" class="task-item">
      <div class="chk-descr">
        <input 
          data-a1="${activity.index}"
          type="checkbox"
          name="completed"
          class="completed"
          />
        <p data-b1="${activity.index}" class="description" contenteditable="true">${activity.description}</p>
      </div>
        <i class="clear-item fa fa-trash"/></i>
    </li> 
    `);
    const listItem = document.querySelectorAll('.task-item')[0];
    const clearItem = document.querySelectorAll('.clear-item')[0];
    clearItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      display.removeChild(listItem);
    });
  });
};
```

The display is working perfectly. However, I am having no success in clearing the items. No success, that is, unless the item selected is the one at the very top of the list. In that case, the item is removed from display, but I obtain the following error:

`Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

When clicking on the items below that one, there is no response at all.

I understand that this has to do with using `insertAdjacentHTML` to insert the items into `display` but I do not know what I can use in its stead. `remove(listItem)` also does not work.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can enlighten me in regards to this matter.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.clear-item')[0]` is always the first element of the class. Why wouldn't that always remove the first one?

Comment: agree.  You hard-coded it to only delete the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the click handler every time you add the item, you can delegate it to the document.body just once. Then look for the class on the item clicked, and if it matches your delete button remove that button's parent node.

```js
const renderList = (activities) => {
  const display = document.getElementById('task-list-display');
  activities.forEach((activity) => {
    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` 
    <li id="task-item" class="task-item">
      <div class="chk-descr">
        <input 
          data-a1="${activity.index}"
          type="checkbox"
          name="completed"
          class="completed"
          />
        <p data-b1="${activity.index}" class="description" contenteditable="true">${activity.description}</p>
      </div>
        <i class="clear-item fa fa-trash"/>DELETE</i>
    </li> 
    `);
  });
};

renderList([
  {"index": "0","description" : "test","title" :"tests" },
  {"index": "30","description" : "xtest","title" :"testsX" }
]);

document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if(el.classList.contains("clear-item")){
    el.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='task-list-display'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @imvain2, delegating the click handler to the document.body resolved the issue entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The code `const listItem = document.querySelectorAll('.task-item')[0];` can return another item which is not child of display.

You can set different id for each list Item and clear Item. Like this.

```
const renderList = (activities) => {
  const display = document.getElementById('task-list-display');
  activities.forEach((activity) => {
    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` 
    <li id="task-item-${activity.index}" class="task-item">
      <div class="chk-descr">
        <input 
          data-a1="${activity.index}"
          type="checkbox"
          name="completed"
          class="completed"
          />
        <p data-b1="${activity.index}" class="description" contenteditable="true">${activity.description}</p>
      </div>
        <i id="clear-item-${activity.index}" class="clear-item fa fa-trash"/></i>
    </li> 
    `);
    const listItem = document.getElementById('task-item-'+${activity.index});
    const clearItem = document.getElementById('clear-item-'+${activity.index});
    clearItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      display.removeChild(listItem);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the item at the end, it will be the last element in the list returned by `querySelectorAll()`, not the first. So use

```
    const allTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-item');
    const listItem = allTasks[allTasks.length-1];
    const clearItem = listItem.querySelector('.clear-item');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it with this code  :

```
clearItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      display.removeChild(display.firstElementChild);
    });
```

cause you are not telling the `removeChild()` the target child correctly